# How to connect my java code to cloudant no-sql?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I used java liberty with cloudant in watson services. And i got my starter code as a zip file.
I have sample code how to connect it to cloudant no-sql db. Please explain me?
I used java liberty with cloudant no-sql. I have starter code. How to connect my java code to no-sql?

Comment: Where is your sample code.?

Comment: sample code in the sense. It's an application that which takes .pdf files and gives names of the organization only that which in  .pdf files. i have to show that data in db.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've bound your Cloudant service instance to your Java Liberty application you have basically two ways to interact with the Cloudant NoSQL DB:

- using a [Client Library](https://docs.cloudant.com/libraries.html)
- directly call the Cloudant [REST APIs](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html)

The Client Libraries are basically wrappers of simple API calls, they only provide you an additional level of abstraction avoiding you to deal with the requests and responses.

Since you are working on a Java application I'd recommend to use the [java-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) library, I've used it in the past and it works fine. Please take a look at the README to understand how to install and use it. The *Getting Started* section shows use how to use the *CloudantClient* Class, that is the main Object you'll have to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And i have done with java-cloudant library and i got code of that in a zip file. Now i have a java code of cloudant db in eclipse. Now how i have to include my java application code with cloudant...!